# How to use C++ 11's using keyword for template function to remove namespace in a scope

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a template function:

```
namespace Example
{
   template<class T>
   T Foo() { return T(0); };
}
```

I would like to use a `using` statement or similar so that I do not have to prefix the function name with it's namespace when calling it i.e.

```
template<class T> using Foo = Example::Foo<T>;
```

However this does not work.

I ***do not*** want to use the following approach as it would include everything form the namespace `Example`:

```
using namespace Example;
```

Is there a nice C++ 11 way to create a shortened alias to a function in a namespace?

Comment: `auto` keyword, not `using`, but this is a C++14 variable template.

Comment: No, that would do a different thing, it would create a variable which would hold a pointer to Foo (actually as many such variables as there are instantiations of the resulting value). The `auto` thing would be equivalent to `template< typename T > T (*Foo)() = Example::Foo< T >;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for any symbol, you can do `using Example::Foo;`. This can be used either in namespace scope, or in function scope (this is actually present in C++98, it is not new in C++11). The approach you were trying to do works only for types, while `Foo` is a function.

Comment: This doesn't work at the class level:

`class
{
 using Example::Foo;
};`

Whereas the example I gave `template<class T> using Foo = Example::Foo<T>;` would work for template classes at the class level.

Comment: No, it does not, if you want to do this for functions on class level, you would have to define wrapper function: `template< typename T > static T Foo() { return Example::Foo(); }`. It is not clear what using in class scope should do, should it import function as static? Should it be visible from outside? etc. Also, for the same reason, I suggest you don't use wrappers as I suggested just for convenience, there should be good reason for it.